# Python sample code to get the list of alerts in grafana

Tags: python, grafana-alerts

Very new to python. I am in need of a sample code in python that would allow me to get the list of alerts/alarms configured in Grafana. Thanks for your help.

I have tried googling and searching on github but what I could get was a code to create new alarms. But I just want to get the list of alarms. Don't really know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a python package for this exact usage `grafana_alerts`. You want to get Grafana alerts onto your python script using some sort of API.

Installation: `pip install grafana_alerts`

> You'll have to create a config file
> /etc/grafana_alerts/grafana_alerts.cfg
>
> ```
> #
> # Grafana alerts configuration file.
> #
>
> # The URL where grafana server is listening. It must finish with the character '/' (default value: http://localhost:3130) grafana_url =
> http://yourgrafanaserver.com/grafana/
>
> # Grafana token with viewer access (default value: empty string) grafana_token =
> qwertysDssdsfsfsdfSFsfsfEWrwrwERwrewrwrWeRwRwerWRwERwerWRwerweRwrEWrWErwerWeRwRwrewerr==
>
> # email to use as alert sender (default value: grafana-alert@localhost) email_from = alert@example.com
>
> # smtp server to use (default value: localhost) smtp_server = localhost
>
> # smtp server host to use (default value: 25)
> # if port is not 25, starts a tls session. smtp_port = 25
>
> # smtp server username to use if it is needed. Optional. Leave it commented if not used. (default value: no username)
> #smtp_username = my_smtp_username
>
> # smtp server password to use if it is needed. Optional. Leave it commented if not used. (default value: no password)
> #smtp_password = my_smtp_password
> ```
>
> Add the task to execute it for example each 3 minutes:
>
> `*/3 * * * *     grafana_alerts`

Read more about the [package](https://pypi.org/project/grafana_alerts/) and [repository](https://github.com/pabloa/grafana-alerts).